# Sample Size and No. of Events in Logistics Regression Model

Tags: regression, logistic

I want to develop a logistic regression model. There are 1000 cases in the dataset and there are only 180 'Yes'. Therefore, the proportion is 18%. 
I was told that I should have at least 500 Yes in the dataset in order to build a good logistic regression model. How can I handle this problem? Do I need to have at least 500 Yes??

Comment: Who told you that? It's simply not true.

Comment: I don't think there is a rule about total sample size N, number of successes, and number of covariates (which is another aspect of the problem that you should describe in your question). You might consider using a penalized likelihood model (such as firth logit) or a rare event logit (King and Zeng), and see if you get very different results from the standard case. Another approach is to simulate your data using the estimated parameters to gauge the amount of finite sample bias.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov well, no. Of course the rule cited by the OP makes no sense at all, but you can find a lot of rules to choose your sample size for logistic regression, based on the power of your test to reject the null. For example see here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11724/minimum-number-of-observations-for-logistic-regression where I would use 0.18 instead than 0.5, given that the sample is unbalanced, or see here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression#6086

Comment: PS 180 "Yes" out of a sample of size $N=1000$ is not a case for serious concern.

Comment: I completely agree with other comments that no such rule exists. If the question is about the sufficiency of sample size, I recommend a power analysis. I have provided a relatively complex example to a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322974/how-can-i-be-sure-my-sample-size-is-large-enough-for-conditional-logistic-regres/323287#323287)

Comment: Consider this:  yesterday I was running a regression using 5,000 "Yes"s out of 37,000 cases.  Even with these numbers, I kept getting errors (singularity in the Hessian Matrix) because my predictors had many categories and this resulted in cells that had either 0 "Yes"s, 0 "No"s, or 0 cases at all.